# Why Is This Jump Discontinuity Not Differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x) = 2x$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=2x+1$ for $x>0$. Why is this function not differentiable? I understand that if a function is differentiable, then it has to be continuous which this function is not. That being said, I am trying to understand it in a different way such as by using the Epsilon-Delta definition.

For example, $\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{2(x+h)+1-(2x+1)}{h}=2$ and $\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{2(x+h)-2x}{h}=2$. So, wouldn't both the one-sided limits imply the limit as $h$ goes to zero for the function going to $2$ imply it is differentiable? I feel like I am doing something wrong here. Maybe negating the Epsilon-Delta Definition would be better.

Comment: Smart! The problem is that you should use a unique value of $f$ at zero which you have not defined.

Comment: Can you explain more? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: It is not continuous at $0$

Comment: The definition of the derivative at $0$ is$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}h.$$What's $f(0)$?

Comment: The definition of the derivative at $0$ is the limit of the quotient $(f(h) - f(0))/h$. What is $f(0)$ in your example?

Comment: You have to choose a unique value for $f(0)$ and then take the limits $$
\frac{2h+1-f(0)}{h}\,,\quad \frac{2h-f(0)}{h}
$$ In each of your limit you use another $f(0)$ and there should be no $x\,.$ At $x\not=0$ the function is clearly differentiable.

Comment: Jump discontinuities in general are not differentiable.  You have already written that 
At the point $(0, f(0) )$, the function is not continuous, much more so does the function does not exist.  Either one of these conditions is sufficient to make the derivative.  Why are you thinking that the derivative does exist there?
Why would the derivative exist when $x=0$?

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(x+h)+1-(2x+1)}{h}=2$ only proves that for $x>0$, $f'(x)=2$. Likewise,  $\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{2(x+h)-2x}{h}=2$ only proves that for $x<0$, $f'(x)=2$. They prove nothing about $f'(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(x+h)+1-(2x+1)}{h}=2$ only proves that for $x>0$, $f'(x)=2$. Likewise, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(x+h)-2x}{h}=2$ only proves that for $x<0$, $f'(x)=2$. They prove nothing about $f'(0)$.

For $f$ (or rather, an extension of $f$ by some choice for $f(0)$) to be differentiable at $0$, both limits
$$a:=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{2h+1-f(0)}h=2+\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1-f(0)}h$$and$$b:=\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{2h-f(0)}h=2-\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(0)}h$$
should first *exist* (and moreover, be equal).
But $b$ exists iff $f(0)=0$ and $a$ exists iff $1-f(0)=0$.